# Config File - Centralize value in App Settings and use in Connection Strings

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config

Not sure if this is possible or not but figured it does not hurt to ask either way.

Have a situation where it would be a lot easier to declare a variable in the App Settings `<add key="database" value="dbName" />` and then "Theoretically" reference in a Connection String element, such as `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=%database%;Persist Security Info=True;Pooling=False;Integrated Security=yes" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Im sure syntactically that the `%database%` would not be good, but just so it offsets where I would place it.

Currently I have 5 Connection Strings that use the same database, different schema accesses to each and different accesses roles to object components.

It would be easier as well for deployment if all I had to do was simply edit the App Setting key and by proxy it would propagate with all the others through reference.

Im sure some of you are gonna say just make the connection string a App setting itself and then do a Find and Replace for the keyword, but im looking for solution that does not slight-of-hand modifications in either the App_Load or otherwise.

Again, this is a brain-storming idea and wanted to throw this across others that maybe "hell-of-a-more knowledgeable" than I.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transforms for config files. 
You can also refer to [Oleg Sych - config transforms](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/12/config-file-transformation/).

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="xyz" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=fbi;User Id=test;Password=test" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**web.release.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="xyz" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```